# Autoreplace string with hyperlink using quick parts in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Is it possible to create a [quick part](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-outlook/archive/2009/02/02/living-in-outlook-using-quick-parts.aspx) that autoreplaces a string with an hyperlink in Outlook 2010? I would like to avoid the vba used in the question [Convert Plain Text to Hyperlink in Outlook](https://superuser.com/questions/635935/outlook-convert-plain-text-to-hyperlink) .

### Example

- if I type (and press F3)

> google something

- It replaces it with the hyperlink

> [something](https://www.google.nl/?q=something#newwindow=1&q=something)

Which links to:

```
https://www.google.nl/?q=something#newwindow=1&q=something
```

Comment: You may avoid VBA *and* quick-parts by using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to create a shortcut macro that issues the keys that do the job.

Comment: Although I like the idea and would go with the solution if it was my private computer, I'm not allowed to install software, without a lot of approvals and lengthy procedures at work.

Comment: AHK is portable so doesn't require installation. The file AutoHotkey.exe is all that is needed to launch any .ahk script.

Comment: I'm still curious if there is a outlook only solution, but thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may avoid VBA and quick-parts by using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to create a shortcut macro that issues the keys that do the job.

But since you ask for an Outlook solution, here is a simple (and even somewhat tested) VBA macro to convert the currently selected text to a hyperlink of the type you requested:

```
Sub SelectionToHyperlink()
' Convert the current selection to a hyperlink
If ActiveInspector.EditorType = olEditorText Then
    MsgBox "Can't add links to textual mail"
    Exit Sub
End If
Dim doc As Object
Dim sel As Object
Set doc = ActiveInspector.WordEditor
Set sel = doc.Application.Selection
doc.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=sel.Range, _
    Address:="https://www.google.nl/?newwindow=1&q=" & sel.Text, _
    SubAddress:="", _
    ScreenTip:="", _
    TextToDisplay:=sel.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Will try it, but is there no solution outside using vba's or external software? Something like autoreplace in Word?

Comment: As far as I know, Outlook has no such in-built capabilities. As Quick Parts do not accept parameters they are not a solution.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use vba at work *sigh*, but since I assume your answer covers the functionality I want, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: You could still go in the direction of a AutoHotkey macro.